# Second derivative computation for riemannian manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry

Let M be a riemannian manifold, $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ smooth and let $c$ be a curve on $M$ such that $|c'(0)|=1 $.

Then
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{ds}|_{s} \text{ } f \circ c = df(c(s))(c'(s)) = \langle \nabla f(c(s) , c'(s) \rangle
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

My question is: how dow I compute the following (equivalent) second derivatives? \begin{equation}
\frac{d^2}{ds^2}|_{s=0} \text{ } f \circ c \text{ } = \frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0} \text{ } df(c(s))(c'(s)) = \frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0} \langle \nabla f(c(s)) , c'(s) \rangle
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

I understand the result in the euclidean ($M=\mathbb{R}^n$) case using the latest product formula (since the velocity $|c'|$ is constant):

\begin{equation}
\text{if } M=\mathbb{R}^n \text{ then: } \frac{d}{ds}|_{0} \text{ } \langle \nabla f(c(s)) , c'(s) \rangle = \langle \frac{d}{ds}|_{0} \nabla f(c(s)) , c'(0) \rangle = \langle \nabla (\nabla f)(c(0)) \cdot c'(0) , c'(0) \rangle = \langle \mathcal{H}f(c(0))\cdot c'(0), c'(0) \rangle
\tag{3}
\end{equation}

where $\mathcal{Hf}$ is the hessian matrix of $f$.

But I don't get to write it in the (riemannian) manifold case.

Any help?

Comment: Your calculation for $\mathbb{R}^n$ is incorrect. Note that $c’\cdot c’’=0$ but not $\nabla f\cdot c’’$

Comment: Thank you @Deane ! What if $c$ is also a shortest curve? (any small perturbation is longer)

Comment: Then of course in the $M=R \text{ } $ case, it is a straight line at constant velocity, so $c''=0$, but is that still the case in a riemannian manifold?

Comment: Yes, if you define $c''$ properly. My suggestion is to first write out all of the calculations carefully using local coordinates, the metric as $g_{ij}$, and the connection in terms of Christoffel symbols. Then carefully write out the calculation using notation as you're using here but matching up each term with the corresponding term in the calculation using coordinates. The more abstract notation is more convenient, but it's very easy to make mistakes with it at the beginning.

Comment: Well I guess $c''$ should be defined as a covariant derivative of the field $c'$ along $c'$.
Which calculations exactly are you advising me to write? It'll be hard for sure LOL

Comment: Yeah, the formula for the covariant derivative of $c'$ along $c'$. It's not that bad. When you do differential geometry, you end up doing every calculation at least twice, where the first time is a total mess and the second time is a lot easier. I often redo the same calculation 10 or more times to make it as simple and clean as possible.